# jquery - change a specific word to a link

Tags: jquery, wordpress, replace

I have a html page (on wordpress) with many articles with names. I would like to use jQuery to make a specific string inside `<article> </ article>` tags to be changed to links.

```
$('article.single').each(function() {
   var text = $(this).text();
   $(this).text(text.replace('Name', '<a href="http://xxx.xx/name/">Name</a>')); 
});
```

When I use this code, the name changes correctly, but the entire article is showing as plain text. What should I change?

Comment: share the generated `HTML` of <article class="single">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...but the entire URL is shown in plain text.
```

Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) not [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/), otherwise you get implict html pruning / text decoding (`<` gets `&lt;` etc...)

```
$('article.single').each(function() {
var text = $(this).text();
$(this).html(text.replace('Name', '<a href="http://xxx.xx/name/">Name</a>'));
});
```

[→CodePen](https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/pWpyyK?editors=1010)

Comment: How does this look for multiple words and URLs? Anyway to pass an array

Answer (score 0):

```
var $thetext = $('#the-text');
var typedText = '';
var replaceText = '<a title="best programming help" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/">programming</a>';
var programmingRegex = /programming$/gi;

$thetext.on('keyup', function(data){   
    typedText = $thetext.val();

    var matches = typedText.match(programmingRegex); 
    if(matches){
        typedText = typedText.replace(programmingRegex, replaceText);
        $thetext.val(typedText);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to leave an explanation to your answer.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen ...Thanks sir. Actually, i m new here. in future, i'll remember this.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in PHP to aviod javascript failures.

```
$content = str_replace('Name','<a href="http://xxx.xx/name/">Name</a>',the_content());
```